# Google Sign-in fails with error 12500, along with a strange log right before it

Tags: android, google-signin

My current implementation of the Google Sign-in is as follows:

```
private fun googleLogin() {
    LoginManager.googleSignOut(this)

    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build()

    val signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso)
    val signInIntent = signInClient.signInIntent
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, LoginManager.Account.GOOGLE.code)
}
```

With the result receiver being like this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    Trace.i(resultCode)

    when (requestCode) {

        LoginManager.Account.GOOGLE.code -> {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            handleGoogleResult(task)
        }
    }
}

private fun handleGoogleResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
    try {
        val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        preLogin(LoginManager.Account.GOOGLE, account?.idToken)
    } catch (e: ApiException) {
        if (e.statusCode != GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
            tryTo(LogType.E, true) {
                LoginManager.setLoginResult(this, LoginManager.LogStatus.FAILED, "Failed to Login")
                finish()
            }
        }

        Trace.e(e)
        Crashlytics.logException(e)
    }
}

private fun handleGoogleResult(completedTask: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
    try {
        val account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        preLogin(LoginManager.Account.GOOGLE, account?.idToken)
    } catch (e: ApiException) {
        if (e.statusCode != GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
            tryTo(LogType.E, true) {
                LoginManager.setLoginResult(this, LoginManager.LogStatus.FAILED, "Failed to Login")
                finish()
            }
        }

        //Log.i("e_status_code", e.);
        e.printStackTrace()

        Trace.e(e)
        Crashlytics.logException(e)
    }
}
```

The problem is that it returns error 12500 with the following log right before the exception:

```
===== INTEGER =====
value : 0
NTZ_TABLE : [B@3bdafa63
SMALL_VALUES : [Ljava.lang.Integer;@13f25719
TYPE : int
MAX_VALUE : 2147483647
MIN_VALUE : -2147483648
SIZE : 32
===== end =====
```

What does this mean?

Related question: from the other psts regarding Error 12500, I could surmise that it's mostly the Keystore's SHA1 problem, or an outdated Google Play Services problem. What else could cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

Have you Tried to update your Google Play Services? If you created the release version you will also need a SHA-1 of the release and update it on the developer console.

Comment: What if this problem occurs in the Debug version?

Comment: Also, I've tried looking into the `Google Play services` 'app' in the phone's manager, and I see no options to update it. Just 'Force Stop' and 'Uninstall Updates', both of which are greyed out. How do I update Google Play Services in my phone?